# Object initialization failed in static block

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee, constructor, static-block

I want to create an array of class objects and initialize it also without using any method so i wrote code like this:

```
package test;

public class Test2 {
    private Test2() {
    }

    static Test2[] arr = new Test2[10];
    static {
        for (Test2 ob : arr) {
            ob = new Test2();
        }
        for (Test2 ob : arr) {
            System.out.println(ob);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }
}
```

But when i run this program, i get o/p:

```
null
null
null
null
....
```

Why is it happening? It seems that constructor is not called when i create a new object

Comment: You don't initialize the array contents properly, so why are you wondering what result you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for (Test2 ob : arr) {` gives you a copy of the reference to each element in `arr`. When you write `ob = new Test2();` you're simply changing what `ob` is referring to. This doesn't change what's in the original array.

You need to write code like `arr[n] = new Test2();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is changing `ob` variable 10 times, and never use its value.

At each loop iteration `ob` points to a `null` object in `arr`, then setting its value just changes it to point to `new Test2()`, not related to `arr`

You should use:

```
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        arr[i] = new Test2();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating objects, but they're never stored in the array. You need something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Test2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Initializing array. You are not setting the reference in array to the Test2 instance you initialized.

Answer (score -2):

I think constructor is used to initialize the object that why static method is not creating any object . use new operator followed by constructor to allocate memory to that object in static block to create array of objects.